# JS - using reduce to create percentage of presence in an array

Tags: javascript, json, object, reduce

I'm trying to use reduce to create an object that contains the percentage of presence of various countries in a list.

input:

```
countriesList = ["US","US","US","UK","IT","IT"]
```

desidered output:

```
percCountriesList = [{"country": "US", "weight": 0.5}, {"country": "UK", "weight": 0.1666}, {"country": "IT", "weight": 0.3333}]
```

How I calculate the percentage:

```
const countriesList = ["US","US","US","UK","IT","IT"]
const weightPercCountries = countriesList.reduce((pcts, x) => {
    pcts[x] = (pcts, (pcts[x] ? pcts[x] : 0) + 100 / countriesList.length);
    return pcts;
}, []);
console.log(weightPercCountries)
```

So, I've got the percentages list:

```
[50, 16.666666666666668, 33.33333333...]
```

Now, how I can build the desidered output (country + weight) "jsonized"?
Thanks

Comment: "*I've got the percentages list*" - are you sure, because running your code (in JS Fiddle) results in an empty Array being logged, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vd8jzakq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code produces an empty array (with a few additional properties), because the `x` in your case is a country-shortcut and not an index. So if you do `pcts[x] = ..` you are actually doing something like `pcts['us'] = ...`  which in most cases doesn't make too much sense for an array.

Second, if you want a complex object in you array, you need to create it somewhere ... See for instance the following snippet

1. I defined `reduce` to return an `object`, so I can easily check if the current country (defined by `x`) is already contained or not.
2. If it's not contained, I add a new property to the object, which already holds all properties I want in the result (ie `{ country: x, percentage: 0}`)
3. Now, that I made sure, an object for the current country exists, I can access it via its name and update the percentage. Whether you want `50` or `0.5` is up to you. Either use `100/countriesList.length` or `1/countriesList.length`
4. `reduce` now returns an object like

   ```
    {
      "us": { country: "us", percentage: 0.5},
      "it": { country: "it", percentage: 0.33} 
      ...
    }
   ```

   So to get an array of the values just use `Object.values(...)` which returns all enumerable properties of an object as an array

```js
const 
  countriesList = ["US","US","US","UK","IT","IT"];
  

const 
  weightPercCountries = Object.values(countriesList.reduce((pcts, x) => {
    if (!(x in pcts))
      pcts[x] = { country: x, percentage: 0}
    
    pcts[x].percentage += (1 / countriesList.length);
    return pcts;
}, {}));

console.log(weightPercCountries)
```

Of course you can shorten the callback of the `reduce` (like for instance in Andrew Park's answer). But for sake of readability (especially for someone who seems to be a beginner) I decided in favour of the more explicit code ...

Answer (score 1):

```js
const countriesList = ["US","US","US","UK","IT","IT"]

const r = Object.values(countriesList.reduce((a,c,_,r)=>
  ((a[c]??={'country':c, weight:0}).weight+=1/r.length,a),{}))

console.log(r)
```

The code above uses the `??=` operator to set a property if the property is not yet defined, and uses a comma expression to avoid the need for a braced code block ending with with `return a`.

A less compact version of the code is:

```js
const countriesList = ["US","US","US","UK","IT","IT"]

const m = countriesList.reduce((a,c,_,r)=> {
  if (!a[c]) a[c] = {'country': c, weight: 0}
  a[c].weight += 1 / r.length
  return a
}, {})

// produces:
// {
//   US: { country: 'US', weight: 0.5 },
//   UK: { country: 'UK', weight: 0.16666666666666666 },
//   IT: { country: 'IT', weight: 0.3333333333333333 }
// }

// now take just the object values, and not the keys
const r = Object.values(m)

console.log(r)
```

Comment: To improve the answer - which is already objectively correct - it helps to explain your code, so that people can learn from it, particularly given that use of the [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) operator is tricky to understand if it's not explained.

Comment: While it's now correct, the comment of @DavidThomas still applies. Code only answers are discouraged. You should explain what you are doing ...